# Получить текст до и после определенного знака

Tags: php

Допустим имеется такая строка:

```
$a = 'Author - Title';
```

Как получить из нее отдельно

```
$author = 'Author';
$title = 'Title';
```

используя переменную `$a` ?

Текст каждый раз уникальный, не меняется только знак `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более универсальный вариант можно найти с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
$str = 'Author - Title';

preg_match('~([^-]+)\s+-\s+([^-]+)~', $str, $arr);
list( , $author, $title) = $arr;

var_dump($author, $title);
```

Но и без регулярок эту задачу вполне можно решить:

```
$str = 'Author - Title';

$arr = explode('-', $str);
$author = rtrim($arr[0]);
$title = ltrim($arr[1]);

var_dump($author, $title);
```

Или так:

```
$str = 'Author - Title';

$author = trim(strstr($str, '-', true));
$title = trim(strstr($str, '-'), '- ');

var_dump($author, $title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант

```
<?php
$a = 'Author - Title';
$items = explode(" - ", $a);
$author = $items[0];
$title = $items[1];
```

Так же можете подобрать нужный вариант из [официальной документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.split.php), для php 5 при известных переменных было удобно использовать split, для php 7 рекомендуется замены preg_split(), explode(), str_split()

Comment: Обратите внимание, что разбивается по " - " (пробелы с двух сторон), а не по "-". Иначе результат будет с пробелом спереди или сзади и придется дополнительно удалять пробелы.

Comment: можно же ещё просто разбить по  " - ", а потом обрезать пробелы с помощью trim()

Comment: @SkyFox, вариантов очень много, не зная задачу, не дать лучшее решение. Например можно использовать csv с этим разделителем, если из текстового файла грузится.